# Can't install Lollypop music player in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I cannot install the Lollypop music player in Ubuntu 16.04. I added the PPA and updated, but when I type `sudo apt-get install lollypop`, I an error that there is no package named `lollypop`.

Comment: Which PPA did you add?

Comment: I typed sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnumdk/lollypop

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a package named lollypop for Ubuntu 16.04 in ppa:gnumdk/lollypop. The name of the package for 16.04 is lollypop-xenial. To install it in Ubuntu 16.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnumdk/lollypop   
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install lollypop-xenial
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I already installed lollypop-xenial, but it seems to do nothing at all, i can't find the Lollypop player

Answer (score 0):

If you try an apt install lollypop-xenial, that worked for me. I couldn't explain why really, but when I checked the ppa page, I noticed that the package contained a few different folders for different ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 0):

As I am missing the 50 reputation to comment on [karels](https://askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel) answer I am writing here. I resolved the issue here [in a gitlab issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/gnumdk/lollypop/issues/1433). The package maintainer states that the

> package was just empty

So just

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install lollypop-xenial
```

and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

## Install lollypop on Ubuntu

The program can be installed by adding the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnumdk/lollypop
sudo apt-get update
```

For Xenial, Artful, Bionic, Cosmic simple install it with

```
sudo apt install lollypop
```

More details can be found on the [lollypop ppa page](https://launchpad.net/~gnumdk/+archive/ubuntu/lollypop)

---

*(no `sudo apt install lollypop-<ubuntu-version>`  anymore necessary)*